# How do deal with conan server connection refused?

Tags: c++, conan

I have a docker container which runs as Conan server. I am trying to upload some Conan packages from another docker container to conan server. After entering username and passwd I am getting following error

```
 Error uploading file: conanmanifest.txt, 
    'HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9300): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/files/hello/0.1/demo/testing/0/export/conanmanifest.txt?signature=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZXNvdXJjZV9wYXRoIjoiaGVsbG8vMC4xL2RlbW8vdGVzdGluZy8wL2V4cG9ydC9jb25hbm1hbmlmZXN0LnR4dCIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZGVtbyIsImZpbGVzaXplIjo1OCwiZXhwIjoxNTg1NDQyMjYyfQ.7sHncjZ7J8gV5HENMqCIwLe7b483QfrGJ2PVyolvjC4
         (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f99c84d2e50>: 

Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))'

        ERROR: hello/0.1@demo/testing: Upload recipe to 'my_server' failed: Execute upload again to retry upload the failed files: conanfile.py, conanmanifest.txt. [Remote: my_server]

ERROR: Errors uploading some packages
```

I ran the following command
`docker run -t -p 9300:9999 --name mycont my_conan`

then edited `server.conf` file accordingly

```
port:9300
public_port:9999
host_name: containerIP
```

From now on I expect to reach by `curl http://localhost:9999` but getting

`Failed to connect to localhost port 9999: Connection refused`
PS: From my host to the server, it works perfectly fine. Bu the error is appearing when i want to upload from container to container

Comment: First, I would strongly recommend using Artifactory as a server, not the ``conan_server``.  Then, if you are running conan_server, have you read https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/running_your_server.html#server-parameters, and set the ``public_port`` and ``host_name`` accordingly in your server configuration?

Comment: @drodri pls have look edit. bcz still doesnot work

Comment: You might want to try the full IP address, not ``localhost``. Seems a connection issue between the host and the docker. I would always recommend to try first with the server running in local (it works in Win, Linux, OSX), to debug other possible issues. Please have a look to the above recommendation, and go for Artifactory, it will scale much better, has web UI, better auth integrations, rest API...

Comment: @drodri I did the same as well. but still same issue. I have to use conan server in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by copying a custom config file to docker container. Otherwise I could not override default config file.

```
1. Write custom config file
2. COPY or ADD to image (in Dockerfile)
3. mv custom.conf /path/to/directory/ (from entrypoint)
```